# Find span containing a particular text and replace it using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find span containing "Go" and replace it with some text. i Have couple of spans with same class. I want to find the span based on text it contains and replace it.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
$('span:contains("Go")').text('Replacement text');
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This. And you'd want to use the `.text()` or `.html()` function to replace the contents (`.html()` if you have html mixed with text, otherwise, just `.text()`). https://jsfiddle.net/6sjbp26x/